# Are JWT-signed prices secure enough for PayPal transactions client-side?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, paypal, jwt, next.js

I'm using NextJS with Firebase, and PayPal is 100x easier to implement client-side. The only worry I have is somebody potentially brute-forcing the amount before the token is sent to PayPal. If I JWT sign with a secret key, is that secure enough (within reason) to dissuade people from attempting to manipulate the prices?

I thought about writing a serverless function, but it would *still* have to pass the values to the client to finish the transaction (the prices are baked into a statically-generated site). I'm not sure if PayPal's IPN listener is still even a thing, or even the NVP (name-value-pairs). My options as I see them:

1. Verify the prices and do payment server-side (way more complex)
2. Sign the prices with a secret key at build time, and reference those prices when sending to PayPal.

I should also mention that I'm *completely* open to ideas, and in no way think that these are the 'best' as it were.

Pseudo-code:

```
cart = {
  product: [ obj1, obj2, obj3 where obj = { price, sale_price, etc.}],
  total: cart.products.length
}
```

create an order with PayPal, using the cart array, and mapping over values

`cart.products.map( prod => { return prod.sale_price || prod.price } etc.`

Someone could easily modify the object to make price '.01' instead of '99.99' (for example)

Comment: It's not clear which JWTs you are talking about. Are you concerned about having the product price ID in the client side ?

Comment: No. I'm saying you can't change the payload of a JWT and have it still verify. So on a client, you could *technically* change the amount to .01 (for instance) but it would break the JWT. That way, I could ensure that the amount being charged is the amount that is signed into the JWT.

Comment: I've used Stripe more than Paypal so just an idea. What they do is when you add a new product you get a "price_id"  (a random ID) which is safe to be on client side and you can verify the product using that on server side because the server knows price of the product with that specific price ID. But if you need dynamic pricing using Paypal, the JWT plan works.

Comment: How would that integration flow though? If the client generates the pricing and Paypal encrypts it, how would I run a server function to verify the amount? It'd just get passed back to the client, no?

Comment: I'm not really sure about how your existing flow is. Can you share it ? Perhaps a flowwchart your code ?

Comment: Statically-generated Product JSON file with images/price/etc. Client-side PayPal Checkout instance, passing an array of all of the carts in the cart object. That's it. I'll add pseudo-code in my OP so you can see what I'm talking about.